# Strange Control Display Corruption in MFC App

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, corruption

I have a strange issue I've been unable to diagnose and am hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction. I have a C++ MFC application that collects data from various sources and displays it on the screen. After a random interval (typically around 5-10 minutes), however, the display gets "corrupted" in a way I've never seen or have been able to track down as shown in the image below (left is normal, right is corrupt):

[image: Example of Display Corruption]

The basic symptoms are:

- Up/down arrow images turn into "5"s and "6"s.
- Opening a combo box list results in just the item text displayed (list border and scroll bar is not shown).
- Background colours on some controls don't update or display correctly.
- Z-order is broken and the app controls "leak" through other windows placed on top.
- Pressing Print-Screen with the app in focus no longer captures the window to the clipboard.
- Closing and reopening the window does nothing.
- Restarting the application gets things back to normal.

Things I've tried to eliminate as a possible cause include:

- **Operating System & Computer:** The same issue is present on a variety of systems from Windows 7-64 bit to Windows Xp-32 bit.
- **Multi-threading:** I added a mutex to prevent the display updates from occurring at the same time but it had no effect (as expected).
- **Memory Corruption:** This has been my assumption all along but there are no signs of memory corruption at all. The base display code has been used for years with no similar issue as well as the base networking message library.
- **Specific Code:** I have narrowed down the issue to one specific dialog among a variety of others that show no issue. They all use the same base code which would seem to indicate the issue lies in the specific display code for the dialog. Exactly how or why the issue occurs has eluded me so far.

Any ideas on what the cause might be or how to narrow it down would be great.

**Update 1:**
Doing some more timing/repeatable tests and it looks like leaving this one dialog running for a short while causes the issue. The amount time is consistently between 300-400 seconds before the issue shows up.

Comment: Looks like something, somewhere is causing undefined behavior

Comment: If you're trying to update the controls from multiple threads, that might do it. You should do all your interactions with Windows from a single thread.

Comment: There was a minor part where the controls were updated in the "worker" thread but disabling this had no effect on the issue. I've double-checked and all the control updates are fired from a WM_TIMER in the main thread (the worker thread just collects data in a thread-safe manner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your application could be leaking GDI objects. To check if that is the case, open your task manager and enable the `GDI Objects` column. Observe the number for your process and see if it's increasing continuously.

If that is actually the case, you should read [Detect and Plug GDI Leaks in Your Code with Two Powerful Tools for Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188782.aspx). That MSDN article also offers a tool named `GDILeaks.exe` that should help you identify your GDI Leaks.

In the case where these symptoms surface within a short time, it should be something that is drawn repeatedly that isn't freeing GDI resources properly. Possibly in (or called within) the windows procedure (OnPaint for example).

Comment: Indeed, the GDI object count increases and the display issue occurs once it reaches 10,000. I have 3 custom controls in the dialog so the issue is likely there somewhere. I figured it was a simple thing like this!

Comment: It turned out to be in the OnCtlColor() handler that was calling ::CreateSolidBrush() 30 times/second instead of creating one brush once and returning that handle. Not sure why I did it that way but after a quick test I've confirmed that GDI handles are no longer leaking.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Windows' GUI uses a ttf(?) font for those little icons, and it looks like the font gets destroyed somehow (DeleteObject being called with font's handle?)

Comment: I did try looking for how those arrows are displayed but couldn't find anything. There is some custom font code in there I'll double-check to ensure I'm not deleting/closing something I shouldn't.

Comment: I commented out the custom fonts used in the dialog but it had no effect. There is nowhere in the code where I'm actually deleting/closing handles until the dialog is destroyed (which never comes into play).